# invalid reference image arkit 1.5

Tags: image-processing, ios11, arkit, xcode9.3-beta

I am running the apple sample project of [ARKit 1.5 Image detection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience)
but when I place my reference image inside AR Resource folder and run the app I get following error:

> **Make sure all reference images are greater than 100 pixels and have a positive physical size in meters.**

I don't find any predefined requirements of how should the image be, can anyone explain the required attributes of the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience)

> For each image, use the inspector to describe the physical size of the
>   image as you’d expect to find it in the user’s real-world environment,
>   and optionally include a descriptive name for your own use.

Click on your image and chose size inspector to provide size. :)

[image: Example described in image]

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case, the dimensions were set and the image was named. But the name itself was invalid because I had another file (of a different type) named the same.

If the accepted solution cannot solve your issue, try changing the AR Resource's name.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Solved by using JPEG format instead of PNG