# AR Reference group - Histogram of image is narrow or not well distributed

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, augmented-reality, arkit

I am doing business card augmented reality. When i added my business card to AR Reference group in assets it shows warning message Histogram of image is narrow and not well distributed. (Note: I have given image physical properties value)

Here is the screenshot of my warning message in assets.[image]

And also reffered [invalid reference image arkit 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006651/invalid-reference-image-arkit-1-5/51060301#51060301)

[AR Reference image - The histogram of the image is narrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886821/ar-reference-image-the-histogram-of-the-image-is-narrow) this url but it does not shows any improvement.

Any help much appreciated pls....

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem of Histogram of image is narrow and not well distributed by making your image more contrast and not show about the pattern structure.

As you can see in the picture here

[image]

In this picture you can see the differences and how to avoid these problems.

However, you still can use the images that has two warning messages for the image detection. But it may not so be recognized well. I hope my answer could help you know more about that. You can check more reference here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/602/?time=2236